# Matplotlib Boxplot displayed in a tkinter window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to get a boxplot to be displayed in a tkinter window and I am having a lot of trouble. I am starting to question if it can even be done. I have been using matplotlib.pyplot plt.boxplot to successfully create a boxplot in the console, but I can't get it to display in a tkinter window.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is the boxplot code with a tkinter window:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    win_stat = Tk()
    win_stat.title('Data Analysis')
    win_stat.geometry("700x400+300+150")
    value1=[27,28.3,25.7,26.9,29.9,30,30.03,31.2,27.9,27.1,25.4,26.5,26.2,28.5,29.1,29]

    value2=[26.8,27.9,25.1,28,29,29.6,29.9,30.7,23,27.5,24.3,28,27.5,31.5,30,32]


    box_plot_data=[value1,value2]
    a=plt.boxplot(box_plot_data)
    plt.show()

    lab_plot = Label(win_stat, text = a).pack()
    win_stat.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please show us a minimal working example? What have you tried? What was wrong with what you tried.

Comment: There is an example on ["Embedding in Tk"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html#embedding-in-tk).

Comment: @TheLizzard I added the boxplot code above. I just have no clue how I could possibly get that plot into a tkinter window

Comment: @Lucas Looking at the link that @ acw1668 send, it looks like you need to create a `Figure` then convert the figure to a canvas that you can put in your `tkinter` window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the link @acw1668 gave you, you need to import `FigureCanvasTkAgg`, and then use it to create a canvas widget that you can `place`/`pack`/`grid` in your `tkinter` window like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tk.Tk()

# First create a figure
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
# Create a plot on that figure
plot = fig.add_subplot()

# Plot the values on the figure
value1 = (27, 28.3, 25.7, 26.9, 29.9, 30, 30.03, 31.2, 27.9, 27.1, 25.4,
          26.5, 26.2, 28.5, 29.1, 29)
value2 = (26.8, 27.9, 25.1, 28, 29, 29.6, 29.9, 30.7, 23, 27.5, 24.3, 28,
          27.5, 31.5, 30, 32)
box_plot_data = (value1, value2)
plot.boxplot(box_plot_data)

# Create a canvas widget from the figure
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
# And then `.pack` it
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried running your code and I get an error that says: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'boxplot'. Did the code work for you? Thanks for your continued help!!!

Comment: @Lucas Are you sure you copied my code correctly? Also the only time I use `plot` is ion these lines: `plot = fig.add_subplot()` and `plot.boxplot(box_plot_data)`. According the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) `.add_subplot` shouldn't return `None`. The code works on my end

Comment: Ok well I think I might of figured out the issue. If I use Spyder 3 the code gets the error. However, if I use Spyder 5 the code works perfectly. I have no clue why any thoughts? Thanks for your time you have already helped out so much!

Comment: @Lucas I have never used `spyder`. It might be a bug in `spyder` that was fixed. I have only used VSCode/IDLE so I don't know why that might be.

Comment: Ok well I'll look into thanks for your help you really came in clutch!!!